# Guitar finger style and strumming

Tags: guitar, fingerstyle-guitar, strumming

I started playing January this year and find finger style easier than strumming.

My question is, can I transform a finger style pattern to strumming, and if yes, how?

Comment: I wonder do you mean "picking" rather than "strumming"?

Comment: yeah I do :) finger picking

Answer (score 1):

Finger style requires a steady hand, often anchored, so that each finger can move independently, usually one string per finger. Strumming involves a rather different action of the whole arm moving up and down, usually with a pick held between finger/s and thumb.

So, the transition is quite stark. I think the only way, if you're not happy strumming like most players do, would be to use all digits, and pluck five strings simultaneously. This would give a sort of strumming effect, with a lot of control over each individual string, unlike ordinary strumming - volume, attack, etc., but would not give much propensity for 'strumming' any fast rhythms.